# I am trying to attach a local repository to github, but cannot

Tags: git, github, repository

I am a git/github newbie and trying to learn the system. When I create a github respository while on the github website and then connect it to a local repository, all works fine. However, when I follow the instructions from github on how to create a github repository remotely, it does not work. I cut and pasted the code right out of a the github page that comes up when a repository is first made. I then delete the github repository and try to create the github repository remotely. Here is the cut and paste.

**Instructions for creating a new repository on the command line:**

```
echo "# my-test-repository" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/mygithubname/my-test-repository.git
git push -u origin main
```

Upon executing the last line, I get a request for my github ID and password, then this message:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/mygithubname/my-test-repository.git/' not found
```

I though I was creating a github repository from a remote location? I have no problem when I create the github repository while at the github site and then populate it after I return to my remote location with a git push.

Another data point: The following line is in my .git/config file after I do the above...

url = https://github.com/mygithubname/my-test-repository.git

So I know that something of a linkage was attempted.

### Help and TIA.

Comment: mygithubname and my-test-repository should be replaced with your own user name and repository name on github

Comment: Actually it was my real user name. So as not to embarrass myself I changed it. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to first create the repo on github before you are able to use it as a remote. You can not force github to create a new repo just by trying to push. And because you are pushing the branch from your local, when setting it up on github, do not ask to create an initial commit.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that answer, but that first line on the github page is confusing. Can you elaborate: …'or create a new repository on the command line"

Comment: Creating a new repository on the command line is what you did with `git init`.... but that doesn't create a repo in github. It's just a _local_ repo. You need to go to github an create _another_ repo there. Then you can use the github repo as a remote to your local repo (which you have added as a remote when you did `git remote add`).